# search data via date with jdatechooser database

Tags: java, netbeans

write the simpliest code on trying to search data via date with jdatechooser . search same date to database? and it will show on Jtable.I can't seem to find this question, all i see is how to find data between dates .

Comment: So you want only data from one date and not between two dates is that correct? Can't you modify those examples it should be pretty simple if you know how to do the rest between two dates already.

Comment: i don't really know how to do the two dates either , I'm new to this.